# Chrome is overriding the specified font-size in my CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-size

I am new to html/css but was assigned to get a html webpage done. When I specified a `font-size` for my webpage and was surprised to find that it was adjusted by my browser (Google Chrome), but I'm not sure why. I specified the `font-size` at `14px` and it was adjusted to be `14.3999996185303px` by the browser, which makes my webpage a little ugly. I would like to understand when the browser will change the value I specify and how I can force the browser to use the value I specify. It would be great if someone can refer me to some material so I can have a good understanding of it.

Comment: please share your CSS code that sets the font-size.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the `font-size` on a couple of elements, you can use a class or id and set the `font-size: 14px` within them. I would assume the problem lies in the fact that chrome is applying a style to your webpage which is overriding the style you provide. Styles on the class will always override those on a tag, and styles on an id will always override those on a class.

Answer (score 0):

**Determining what is causing a certain style using Chrome Developer Tools.**

The Chrome Developer Tools allow you to analyze an element and see all the styles that are being applied to it. You can see where each rule is coming from, and which rules are overridden by other rules. To analyze a certain element on a page, right click on that element (for example, a paragraph of text) and choose "Inspect Element". You can also open the dev tools manually and click around in the DOM (the live representation of the HTML source code) to select a certain HTML element.

When you hover over an HTML element in the DOM (the main pane of the "elements" tab), it will highlight it on the browser page. When you click on it in the DOM, it will show the CSS rules that are applied to it on the right pane. For each selector, you can see which CSS file it's coming from. The rule will have a line through it if it is being overridden, and will be grayed out if it is irrelevant.

Try using this tool to see if your rule is being overridden by something.

**Forcing something to take precedence over everything else in CSS.**

Normally, CSS rules heirarchy is based on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). If two rules conflict, the browser will use the one that has a more specific selector. You can force a CSS rule to take precedence over everything else, even over things that were overriding it previously, by using the `!important` decorator. This will even override browser rules, such as the styling of form controls.

Avoid using this. It is not considered good practice because when you have a lot of CSS code that uses the `!important` it becomes very difficult to understand and debug.

To use the `!important` decorator, simply put the decorator before the semicolon. The example below demonstrates specificity, and overrides the specificity using the decorator.

```css
p.test {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  /* this rule will be applied, even though the `p`
   * selector has a lower specificity than `p.test`. */
  color: #FF0000 !important;
  /* this rule will not be applied, because the
   * specificity is not being overridden. */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">
  This is a paragraph.
</p>
```